# Is a noun 'Lyrics' a mass noun?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

Additional information:

> According to the [source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lyric) a noun 'lyrics' as text of a song it isn't a mass noun; It means that it has singular and plural cases for such noun, but according to its examples there're no cases with singular *'lyric'* noun.

Question:

1) Does it exist the only option for the noun 'lyric**s**' as plural or sometimes the noun 'lyric**s**' could be singular in terms of using it for defining text of song entity

2) In case when the noun 'lyrics' can be only plural then can I treat *(perceive)* the noun 'lyrics' as a mass noun in spite of Oxford dictionary determination? *- I think no because mass nouns are uncountable*

Examples:

> singular: Her first **lyric** for the song is great
>
> plural: Her first **lyrics** for the song are great

Comment: A noun  can only be called a count noun if it can combine with the cardinal numbers. So if you're happy saying that so-and-so wrote 15 lyrics, then yes, it can in examples like that be called a count noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Lyrics* is a tricky word. I've often seen the word *lyric* used in a singular form, particularly when referring to a particular line or a couplet of a song.

Around a century ago, in January 1917, *Writer's Monthly* chronicled the birth of a song called *There's a Quaker Down in Quaker Town*, using the singular form to refer to the title line:

> Berg took the lyric to a number of other publishers, only to become a laughingstock. But again he went back to the Morris firm. This time he showed the lyric to Alfred Solomon, a composer, under contract to Morris. Solomon liked the lyric and wrote a melody for it. Then he offered the complete song to Morris.

In the modern era, Beach Boy Carl Wilson tosses around the words *lyric* and *lyrics* in an almost seemingly interchangeable way:

> "On the first day of our collaboration, Brian played me the melody for a song he'd written. If I remember correctly, the original melody sounded exactly the way it does on the album, and someone had already written **lyrics**. Brian never played me the existing **lyric** -- he played the instrumental trace and said, 'I don't even want you to year the **lyric** that's been written." He ... then went to the piano and made a second tape, with him playing the melody and singing dummy **lyrics**. I took the cassettes from that first day home, and wrote the **lyric** to what became know as 'You Still Believe in Me'."
>   <sub>Source: "Wouldn't It Be Nice: Brian Wilson and the Making of the Beach Boys' Pet Sounds", Granata and Asher, 2016.</sub>

I would say that a song has **lyrics**, but we can refer to the **lyric** of a song, a term which often refers to a subset of the song's full lyrics.

Answer (score -2):

- [Lyrics](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lyric) is a countable noun.

As a singular noun is mostly means *"A short poem that expresses the personal thoughts and feelings of the person who wrote it"*

As a plural noun is most often means *"The words of a song"*

As a mass noun is means *"Lyric poetry as a literary genre"*

If you want to speak about a particular part of the lyrics of a song it is better to say:

- The second line of the lyrics has a grammar mistake in it.
- The chorus in the lyrics is amazing.

Comment: Why the downvotes?